# How to Get Data From PHP C#

Tags: c#

I have a Php Script in my Host Which has the link of my new version of my Program,How Can I Get that link From Php? I mean I wanna get that link From Php and Save it in one String.

I Often Use This Code For Doing Something like this:

`webbrowser.Nagative("MyPhp Uri");`

`webbrowser.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);`

`webbrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);`

Than I Paste it in one Textbox

```
textbox1.Paste();
```

But This Way is not Complete way to get data From Php?
Can you help me?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  Question is not clear.

Comment: Use restful api .expose a api in php and call it from c# code

Comment: I'm New Member here; I'm So sorry. probably I'll get -100 Score After 1 houre.

Comment: Appreciate that English might not be your first language, but I cannot tell from your question as written, what you're stuck with, and what's not working for you?

Comment: Why are you Telling this? I just told a little Good Example. But I know I am New Member And I don't know how to ask good question; I mean I don't know How to ask Question in better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use webrequest instead.
I'm not posting a complete solution because I'm pretty sure you will find one as soon as you know what to search for:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

//create a request object and server call
Uri requestUri = new Uri("MyPhp Uri");
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.requestUri);
//set all properties you need for the request, like
request.Method = "GET";
request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ProcessResponse), request);


//handle response
private void ProcessResponse(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    string responseData = string.Empty;

    HttpWebRequest myrequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myrequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult))
    {
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        responseStream.Close();
    }
    //TODO: do something with your responseData 
}
```

Please notice: you should definitively add some try/catch blocks.. this is only a short example to point you in the right direction.